# Changing Emacs CC mode indent style

Tags: emacs, indentation, cc-mode

I'm an emacs newbie and I've been trying to set up my indent style for cc-mode. I like to write code like this:

```
if(true)
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

But the default indent style is more like:

```
if(true)
  {
    foo();
    bar();
  }
```

It seems the indent style I want is "bsd" while the default is "gnu". I put the following in my init.el file to change the settings:

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd")
(setq c-basic-indent 4)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```

This changed the offset and the default style, but when I typed some code out, it was still formatted like the gnu style. To clarify, I would type out `if(true) [ENTER] { [ENTER] foo(); [ENTER] }` and the result would be the gnu style code. I also tried putting this in my init.el, for the same results:

```
(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
(setq c-basic-offset 4
    c-indent-level 4
    c-default-style "bsd"))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
```

I could tell the settings were definitely changed because in the minibuffer I evaluated this expression `(message "%s %s %d" c-default-style c-indentation-style c-basic-offset)` to get this result: `"bsd bsd 4"`

I am using [graphene](https://github.com/rdallasgray/graphene). Is it possible that one of its included packages (smartparens or autocomplete maybe) could be interfering with my settings?

Comment: It seems that you're doing the right thing.
You should ask here: https://github.com/rdallasgray/graphene/issues.
Also have a look at https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit,
to see why pre-packaged starter kits aren't the best way to go.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2461962/113848).